# Filter DataFrame of dtype object using pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm required to parse data using the following operations.

```
data=[{'a': 1, 
       'b': {1: 1, 
             2: 2}, 
       'c': ['q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y']},  
      {'a': 2, 
       'b': {1: 2, 
             2: 3}, 
       'c': ['q', 't', 'a', 'v', 'o', 'l']}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to get data that satisfy a condition as follows:

```
print(df['q' in df.c].head())
```

However, I get an error:

```
File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 676, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12216)
KeyError: False
```

Why wouldn't this work?

I'm confused as the following code would work unlike when parsing through the object dtype:

```
print(df[df.a == 1].head())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` on the column to generate a boolean mask describing the desired columns, and then filter the DataFrame by this mask:

```
>>> df[df.c.apply(lambda val: 'q' in val)]
   a             b                   c
0  1  {1: 1, 2: 2}  [q, w, e, r, t, y]
1  2  {1: 2, 2: 3}  [q, t, a, v, o, l]
```

Comment: Thanks. But Can I use this method for same multiple values, for eg, 'q' and 't' ??

Comment: you could use ``'q' in val or 't' in val``

Answer (score 1):

`in` is used for index checking. For values you can use `str.contains()`:

```
df.c.str.contains("q", regex=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer anyway!

Comment: This won't work though as col c contains lists as the elements

Comment: @EdChum, It works, because contains use `in` when `regex` is `False`.